# How to run Filters on those devices that are not compatible with google play store AR services?

Tags: android

So, I was making app and it does capture and apply live filter, my codes are fine, but soon after I realize that I do need to have installed Google AR services, which are not compatible with my REDMI 8 (though, according to many sites, redmi 8, should support AR services), so my 1st question was does My device really not support ar servies,and second was that, then how AR filters of instagram runs on even my device?
Hope, you can help me.
[image][image]

Link of video
https://youtu.be/Y4hxhDNL37w

Comment: Cause tutorial I was watching said so and when I run app , it itself says installing ar core and takes me to play store on OWN, saying I need to install and then says my device is incompatible so Google play services for Ar is required

Comment: I doubt that. It likely says that Google AR services can be used to help with those issues. That doesn't mean that you can't access camera data in other ways and interact with that. When writing a question you should link to resources like such a video, so that it's easier to see where your issue is.

Comment: As I said earlier, on opening app, dialogue box saying installating ar core is required, then box to open play store appears as I have pasted screenshot in question by edit, now can you help

Comment: https://youtu.be/Y4hxhDNL37w

Comment: @Christain See now I gave you video, and see it does not says likely, it is literally taking me to ar core, and saying my device do not support so and hence only I asked that how Instagram run at filter on my device then

Comment: If that screenshot appear then you are using a library that needs AR service. If you don't have the service on your phone and can't install it, you can't use the library.

Comment: So isn't what exactly I was saying and dude ,  my question was that how can Instagram run its filter, aren't they also ar services and this tutorial was I watching, maybe now you can help me  https://youtu.be/w8rakQD4jf4

Comment: They likely work directly with the camera API.

Comment: Thanks so doing with directly camera API will not force me to have ar services, thank you, hope there are any tutorial on that take care